# How can I connect my domain name to my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, dns, php-7

Before I start, I searched a lot to solve my problem (and by a lot, I mean ... a lot). BTW sorry for my English

Here is my problem: I have a Wordpress site, currently located at the following IP http://192.222.217.18

On this server, I use nginx, php7.0-fpm and mysql, everything was working fine

Now, I bought a domain name (at godaddy.com), this one: http://www.deals-with-it.com/

I "linked" it to my wordpress ip address (192.222.217.18) through the godaddy interface.

After that I simply modified the home and siteurl parameter of wordpress to my new domain name.

And ..... it didn't work.

Now when I try to access my wordpress blog from www.deals-with-it.com, it redirects me to my IP address 192.222.217.18 (I can see my address in the address bar of the navigator, I don't want that), the CSS don't work, and all links are broken ...

I think the problem come from nginx, but I already tried everything on this side ...

I also purged wordpress and reinstalled it, same for the database.

Here is the EXACT state of my my current platform:

**First of all, the godaddy DNS configuration**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNlXk.png)

The IP is not the one I entered (192.222.217.18), but it seems to work anyway

My nginx configuration **/etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress**

```
# Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for php
upstream php {
    server unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    ## Your website name goes here.
    server_name www.deals-with-it.com deals-with-it.com;
    ## Your only path reference.
    root /var/www/wordpress;
    ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
    index index.php;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
            # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass php;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

(The socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock exists)
My wordpress **/var/www/wordpress/wp-config.php** file (only an extract that I modified)

```
define('WP_HOME','http://deals-with-it.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://deals-with-it.com');
// Code for showing correct client IP address
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
    $mte_xffaddrs = explode( ',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] );
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $mte_xffaddrs[0];
}
```

I also added cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0; to my **/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini** file

I have nothing in my nginx logs, they are currently removed but I used to have logs defined in the file **/etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress**, and nothing was wrong (no errors logged by nginx)

I also modified the wordpress database to replace all 192.222.217.18 occurences to deals-with-it.com

I honestly searched everywhere since yesterday, tried a lot of things, and I'm still stuck here, so if you could help me ...

Thank you for your help

Edit: I managed to have the righ address showing in the address bar of my navigator, by changing the IP into godaddy with the right IP, and I also changed the WP_HOME URL to define('WP_HOME','http://deals-with-it.com/wordpress');
But now I have 403 error for all my links

Answer (score 0):

To add your own domain name you just have to configure WordPress to point to your domain. This can be done by adding go daady name-servers (can be found in your go daady account) into WordPress. Search for something like adding name-servers in WordPress. This will do the trick.